# Android Wait For Method Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my database in a social app. I am working on a notifications page to notify the user when someone has commented on their posts, followed them, or tagged them in a post. This requires 3 different parse queries. I have the notifications in a listview, so i would like to wait for all three queries to finish before setting the listview adapter. How do I do this to ensure that all three have finished before setting the adapter?

I currently am doing it by keeping a count and checking the count every time, if the count == 3 then I set the adapter, but this seems to be leaving out things randomly.

Comment: What are the three queries? I see three separate actions that shouldn't wait on each other

Comment: Regardless, you could do `Action1 -> onSuccess() { Action2 -> onSuccess() { Action3 -> onSuccess() { update adapter } } }`